# How to define implementation specific (XC8) int types in pc-lint?

Tags: c, static-analysis, pic, microchip, pc-lint

Microchip XC8 has non-standard int types - __int24 and __uint24 and produced from them (by typedef) int24_t and uint24_t.

However, pc-lint does not know about them. What is the way to make pc-lint know about these types?

Comment: There should be a folder with compiler specific settings in your pc-lint install folder. Have you checked it?

Comment: Include the relevant header file? I would have expected a tool to be able to correctly use any defined type.

Comment: You can use e.g. `-d__int24=int -d__uint24=unsigned`, but then PC-lint will obviously treat the types as ints instead.

Comment: @TimRandall pc-lint is not very intuitive in doing anything automatically. You have to configure the whole lint monster yourself.

Comment: There is file co-xc8.lnt but there is nothing about `__int24` and `__uint24` in it. 
I suppose that a good solution could be `-d__int24=int32_t`, `-d__uint24=uint32_t`, also `-dint24_t=int32_t`, `-duint24_t=uint32_t`.